# Windows.Devices.SmartCards SmartCardReader slows appliction shutdown process

Tags: c#, wpf, smartcard-reader

In a WPF desktop application using Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts (version 10.0.22621.755) I simply call the following code while debugging in Visual Studio.

```
SmartCardReader scr = await SmartCardReader.FromIdAsync(@"the_Device_ID");
```

When I shutdown the application by closing the WPF window, Visual studio takes 10 to 15 seconds to stop running. Is this to be expected or am I not cleaning up something I should in Windows.Devices.SmartCards